# Vue - Storing data best practice

Tags: vue.js

I'm currently using `cookies` to store my `employee_id`. This `employee_id` is needed as a `params` to one of my list in the navigation menu that will redirect them to a private page `/private/:id`. I read that users can edit browser cookies, thus can see other employee's private page.

I also tried vuex and sessions storage.

- Does session storage have an expiration time?
- Is it better to just store the id in the vuex store and call the `setEmployeeID` function in `created()` so even if the user refreshes, the data won't disappear since it is always using axios call to get the id?

Comment: *I read that users can edit browser cookies, thus can see other employee's private page* - users can tamper anything on their side, your goal is to make this unimportant. User should see empty page if they try to access something they are not allowed to. Things that you talk about (auth and time-limited access) are controlled from server side, so Vue's 'best practice' is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Everything** that gets to the client can be edited / viewed, including cookies, storage, etc.

If you have some info that you don't want to be exposed to another users - store it on server and do authentication. Do it using Vuex and you will be fine.

Session storage - is per tab and destroyed when the tab destroyed
Cookies - here is explanation regarding cookies securing: https://blog.dareboost.com/en/2019/03/secure-cookies-secure-httponly-flags/